# Call Django report builder report from a view or template

Tags: django, reporting

I installed django report builder, and i already created a report inside the adminsite, but, how do i call this report from a view or a template in order to make it available for different user from my app?...can't find anything til now. Any tutorial ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can easily import that `Lib` and also `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in your view and then do everything .... if you want have results in your templates then you should use forms

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but im not talking about user model ,what i need is to call a django report builder report inside a view or template

Comment: `for different user from my app` !!! when you want to work with that report builder for other user ( not Admin ) you should work with a user model for current user